# Issue removing Ngons from Interior

Tags: modeling

im currently 3d modelling my first interior for a game for import into UE4 and im having issues with this particular situation. i have a complicated floorplan and want to add winodws and doorways without creating Ngons on the floor here is a picture to show an example [image]

I know i could add an extra edge on the floor but considering i am going to have multiple windows and doorways this can get messy and its for a game so the lower the poly count the better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If low poly count is important then I would suggest you modify your workflow a little to something like the following:

First create your outer walls with window and door openings, then optimize this by merging vertices that are not doing anything to the ones that are.

[image]

Next to create the inner walls use the solidify modifier.

Apply this and then add the floor.

[image]

Just realized that you said that you are only modeling interiors, so no need for solidify modifier.